# Terraform unable to recognize private service access connection for FileStore in Shared VPC

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Terraform is not recognizing "private service access connection" in the host project part of the shared VPC setup. It is complaining on UNSUPPORTED argument : An argument named "connect_mode" is not expected here when trying to create a FileStore instance in the service project.

**Terraform Version and Provider Versions:**

```
Terraform v1.0.11
provider.google version = ">= 3.58, <= 4.28.0"
provider.google-beta ">= 3.39.0, <4.0.0"
```

Terraform Configuration Files

```
resource "google_filestore_instance" "filestoreinstance" {
  provider                     = google
  name                          = "${module.project.project_name}-filestore-usea4-fstore"
  project                       = module.project.project_id
  zone                           = var.zone
  tier                              = "BASIC_SSD"

  file_shares {
    capacity_gb = 2660
    name        = var.filestore_dir_name
  }
        
networks {
    network            = regex(".*/global/networks/(.*)$", local.vpc)[0]  //This is a shared VPC project name (or) Host Project
    modes              = ["MODE_IPV4"]
    connect_mode       = "PRIVATE_SERVICE_ACCESS"
  }
  
labels = var.labels
depends_on = [
    module.subnets,
    module.project
  ]
}
```

**Expected Behavior**

Terraform plan and apply should recognize that there is already a "private service access
connection and create a Filestore instance.
Actual Behavior

```
Error: Unsupported argument

  on main.tf line 199, in resource "google_filestore_instance" "ailoyalinstance":
 199:     connect_mode       = "PRIVATE_SERVICE_ACCESS"
```

**Reference Docs:**

[https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/shared-vpc#gcloud-cli_2:~:text=console-,gcloud%20CLI,-gcloud%20filestore%20instances](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/shared-vpc#gcloud-cli_2:%7E:text=console-,gcloud%20CLI,-gcloud%20filestore%20instances)

Note: This works fine with GCloud SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `connect_mode` argument for that block was added in [version 3.84 of the beta for the provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/3.84.0/docs/resources/filestore_instance#connect_mode). It is absent from the release notes and CHANGELOG for that version for some reason, but you can see the update in the [corresponding PR](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/9951) indicating when and how the feature was added to the beta provider.

Use version >= 3.84 of the `google-beta` provider with that resource, and the argument will be supported.

Comment: Thanks Matt, it kinda helped. Perhaps, when I run apply it fails with invalid network configuration.

Comment: ----------------------------------------------------------
Error: Error creating Instance: googleapi: Error 400: invalid network configuration.

  on main.tf line 178, in resource "google_filestore_instance" "filestoreinstance":
 178: resource "google_filestore_instance" "filestoreinstance" {
---------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: @krish Glad I was able to solve your problem. Feel free to ask a new question for that new problem, and please mark "accepted" the answer that best solves your question.

Comment: Thanks Matt, Perhaps I should say it was poor documentation from terraform registry for this (filestore) resource block, confused me to not identify the right parameters.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/3.84.0/docs/resources/filestore_instance#connect_mode

Two things to be noted here.,

1. google-beta version
2. network name -> should be a string instead of a soft link or just a vpc name, something like this.,

regex(".*/(projects/.*/global/networks/.*)$", local.vpc)[0]